# Firebase javascript authentication - Error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

Here is the code that I wrote that is in question

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(firebaseUser => {
  if(firebaseUser) {
   console.log(firebaseUser);
   } else {console.log('not logged in');
}
```

Yes, I have changed the script from Firebase

Comment: how is firebase defined?

Answer (score 1):

try including `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/[version]/firebase.js"></script>`in your html.